# Why was Ptolemy recording his meeting?

Tags: the-last-days-of-ptolemy-grey

In the final episode of the *[The last days of Ptolemy Grey](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13820498/)* (which is first referenced at the very beginning of the series, so there is no need for the spoiler tag), to avenge the death of his nephew the main character lures the suspected murderer to his house. Ptolemy doesn't trust the police, so from the beginning, his plan is to shoot the killer. However, before the meeting starts, he hides a tape recorder that will store the conversation.

This move makes a little sense to me - why would he try to record that meeting? For the court, that would be evidence showing that he was intending to kill his "guest". Without that tape, he could say that he was acting in self-defence while protecting himself from a well-known criminal.

Was he just acting a bit senile again? Was that sort of a backup plan?